# OpenSSL Certificate: How to sign csr directly to pem file?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

When a csr is signed , I get crt file and then convert to pem. Is there a way to sign csr to get pem directly (one step without conversion)?

I tried "$ openssl ca ... -out cert.pem", but the generated "cert.pem" is still in crt format, i.e. it has human-readable portion before "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----".

Thank you.

Comment: What you tried seems correct. `openssl ca -in req.csr -out cert.pem` should do it. These are just different representations of the same data. `DER` is a binary encoding, `PEM` is pure ASCII, which is the `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` block you see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `outform` parameter, which isn't available on all openssl commands, it is available in the `x509` directive and `req`. If you are looking to create a self-signed certificate you can do it all in one line:

```
openssl req -outform PEM -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
            -keyout mysitename.key -out mysitename.pem
```

Here is a difference between DER and PEM I created on the fly, see the difference?:

```
# cat mysitename.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----


# hexdump mysitename2.der
          00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 - 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F  0123456789ABCDEF

00000000  30 82 03 B5 30 82 02 9D - A0 03 02 01 02 02 09 00  0...0...........
00000010  AE E1 5C 32 AA 72 47 CC - 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86  ..\2.rG.0...*.H.
00000020  F7 0D 01 01 05 05 00 30 - 45 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55  .......0E1.0...U
00000030  04 06 13 02 41 55 31 13 - 30 11 06 03 55 04 08 13  ....AU1.0...U...
00000040  0A 53 6F 6D 65 2D 53 74 - 61 74 65 31 21 30 1F 06  .Some-State1!0..
00000050  03 55 04 0A 13 18 49 6E - 74 65 72 6E 65 74 20 57  .U....Internet W
00000060  69 64 67 69 74 73 20 50 - 74 79 20 4C 74 64 30 1E  idgits Pty Ltd0.
00000070  17 0D 31 34 30 31 30 31 - 30 36 32 37 30 36 5A 17  ..140101062706Z.
00000080  0D 31 35 30 31 30 31 30 - 36 32 37 30 36 5A 30 45  .150101062706Z0E
00000090  31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 - 06 13 02 41 55 31 13 30  1.0...U....AU1.0
000000A0  11 06 03 55 04 08 13 0A - 53 6F 6D 65 2D 53 74 61  ...U....Some-Sta
000000B0  74 65 31 21 30 1F 06 03 - 55 04 0A 13 18 49 6E 74  te1!0...U....Int
000000C0  65 72 6E 65 74 20 57 69 - 64 67 69 74 73 20 50 74  ernet Widgits Pt
000000D0  79 20 4C 74 64 30 82 01 - 22 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48  y Ltd0.."0...*.H
000000E0  86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 - 03 82 01 0F 00 30 82 01  .............0..
000000F0  0A 02 82 01 01 00 B3 00 - 17 31 F1 CD 97 CB AE 68  .........1.....h
00000100  0C 9D 62 82 75 CF 78 C3 - 23 68 EF 57 8A 65 EB C1  ..b.u.x.#h.W.e..
00000110  37 0D 28 78 94 43 BF 1C - 18 FE 03 DB CC 0E D8 08  7.(x.C..........
00000120  AE CB B2 32 2F A4 F0 69 - E7 04 4B 98 93 DB CB 94  ...2/..i..K.....
00000130  A1 3B 9C 9F C8 2B 37 DB - 3B AD F9 15 79 55 D7 8B  .;...+7.;...yU..
00000140  58 8A 5E 92 DC C5 2F B4 - C2 90 E5 58 C8 3E 6D 33  X.^.../....X.>m3
00000150  BA 67 B6 6D 83 03 01 F6 - B9 DB 71 0B 10 13 56 B2  .g.m......q...V.
00000160  F8 42 6F F7 AE 57 86 AA - AE AF D8 BF 39 9E 62 A0  .Bo..W......9.b.
00000170  14 1B D9 5E F4 22 76 0B - 44 58 D1 B2 E8 87 6C 3B  ...^."v.DX....l;
00000180  72 7F D5 E2 89 26 5C 53 - F3 D4 2F 60 E2 67 C1 09  r....&\S../`.g..
00000190  AB 1A 8A 4A 8E 2A C2 07 - C3 CE 02 A3 F8 03 35 E1  ...J.*........5.
000001A0  D8 85 31 11 A6 7B B3 2D - D5 10 9C 74 48 7E 3A 19  ..1..{.-...tH~:.
000001B0  97 FD 89 4C 2E A8 0F 2E - CE FC A1 EE 73 41 15 1D  ...L........sA..
000001C0  71 63 D3 DF ED DA 2C 5A - 7D 3F F2 06 2D C6 6E 10  qc....,Z}?..-.n.
000001D0  39 D7 6F D3 70 32 4A D8 - CC A3 B8 09 3C 52 62 93  9.o.p2J.....<Rb.
000001E0  2B 6E BF 6E FD D7 FA F7 - 19 3D 7D 6D 7C 20 5D 31  +n.n.....=}m| ]1
000001F0  82 07 CC 6E B1 A1 02 03 - 01 00 01 A3 81 A7 30 81  ...n..........0.
00000200  A4 30 1D 06 03 55 1D 0E - 04 16 04 14 09 A1 46 E7  .0...U........F.
00000210  3A E8 6E 17 95 7B 0D 15 - 66 3D BF 92 6D 5D 41 25  :.n..{..f=..m]A%
00000220  30 75 06 03 55 1D 23 04 - 6E 30 6C 80 14 09 A1 46  0u..U.#.n0l....F
00000230  E7 3A E8 6E 17 95 7B 0D - 15 66 3D BF 92 6D 5D 41  .:.n..{..f=..m]A
00000240  25 A1 49 A4 47 30 45 31 - 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06  %.I.G0E1.0...U..
00000250  13 02 41 55 31 13 30 11 - 06 03 55 04 08 13 0A 53  ..AU1.0...U....S
00000260  6F 6D 65 2D 53 74 61 74 - 65 31 21 30 1F 06 03 55  ome-State1!0...U
00000270  04 0A 13 18 49 6E 74 65 - 72 6E 65 74 20 57 69 64  ....Internet Wid
00000280  67 69 74 73 20 50 74 79 - 20 4C 74 64 82 09 00 AE  gits Pty Ltd....
00000290  E1 5C 32 AA 72 47 CC 30 - 0C 06 03 55 1D 13 04 05  .\2.rG.0...U....
000002A0  30 03 01 01 FF 30 0D 06 - 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01  0....0...*.H....
000002B0  01 05 05 00 03 82 01 01 - 00 AE 59 7C 8F A0 F7 75  ..........Y|...u
000002C0  BA 83 63 9F AA A0 7F BF - B4 B1 EC A9 C5 DA 4B 4A  ..c...........KJ
000002D0  D9 40 DC 21 1D 1A 3B 98 - D8 ED 21 40 00 98 A1 FA  .@.!..;...!@....
000002E0  A6 7A 01 F0 C6 A8 E8 BD - 6E AA F5 FA 45 99 C4 20  .z......n...E..
000002F0  AD C8 C7 E3 81 BC FF CD - 48 1D 01 EC 44 3E A2 05  ........H...D>..
00000300  CD 0D 22 62 3B 85 AB A8 - EA 28 D0 AA 76 06 73 41  .."b;....(..v.sA
00000310  10 6D 7A 1B C9 E2 5B F4 - 93 8F 91 A4 25 1B C7 91  .mz...[.....%...
00000320  C7 31 2A D2 00 86 8A 94 - FE DB 48 87 52 A1 0F 3C  .1*.......H.R..<
00000330  BF 2B 1C 32 5C D8 54 AD - 5A 88 31 3A 4C F3 72 37  .+.2\.T.Z.1:L.r7
00000340  30 39 A1 F1 6D 51 2E 4D - 9F D7 50 5C FE A6 91 CA  09..mQ.M..P\....
00000350  03 36 BA 4D 5F C0 48 8C - D4 FB BB 98 F1 85 11 DB  .6.M_.H.........
00000360  BC 16 DA 99 52 A7 82 46 - 82 63 8F D3 F7 5F 00 96  ....R..F.c..._..
00000370  E1 C0 A4 CE 18 61 61 E9 - 84 C3 F6 BD B1 12 9D D4  .....aa.........
00000380  FE AF 87 7B 49 25 A4 0C - 51 5E 20 03 EE 32 64 65  ...{I%..Q^ ..2de
00000390  53 4B 8F CF FC AF 07 6F - 54 96 3F BF A8 85 11 D2  SK.....oT.?.....
000003A0  D3 25 51 60 78 1C DD D3 - 75 35 A8 B4 C9 A2 81 30  .%Q`x...u5.....0
000003B0  A4 87 7F A8 91 B4 32 09 - 5C                       ......2.\
```